# Which is correct? As soon as the class resume? or As soon as the class resumed?

Tags: grammar

Which of the question above is grammatically correct? As soon as the class resume? or As soon as the class resumed?. Or there is a better statement for that? Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion either could be correct depending on context. Is that the whole sentence or the start of a longer one? Are you talking about a "class" in the sense of a group of students or in the sense of a specific lesson? Please [edit] your question to provide more context.

Comment: Are you talking about the future or the past? It isn't a question, it's a phrase; you need to go on to say what will happen when the class resumes, (or what happened when it resumed).